# How do I compare the data received by new activities in java and xml global strings? (Android)

Tags: android, android-intent, if-statement, android-activity

I am writing a multiple choice quiz using Eclipse for Android with 4 buttons for the possible answers.

in the `AskQuestion` class I have put the following:

```
public void Answer1Pressed(View view){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(AskQuestion.this, CheckQuestion.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("answer", 1); //Optional parameters
        AskQuestion.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
    public void Answer2Pressed(View view){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(AskQuestion.this, CheckQuestion.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("answer", 2); //Optional parameters
        AskQuestion.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
    public void Answer3Pressed(View view){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(AskQuestion.this, CheckQuestion.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("answer", 3); //Optional parameters
        AskQuestion.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
    public void Answer4Pressed(View view){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(AskQuestion.this, CheckQuestion.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("answer", 4); //Optional parameters
        AskQuestion.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

This should send a string called *answer* which declares which button was pressed - Is that what is actually happening ?

In the `CheckQuestion` class I have the following code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_check_question);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        intent.getStringExtra("answer");
```

Which should receive the answer string from the intent sent when the button is pressed - will this work  ?

I want to add an if condition to check if the value for "answer" is the same as the global variable for `CorrectAnswer` that I have set up in res/values folder, but I am struggling to make it work.

Thanks for any help or advice.

Comment: Why not use `RadioButton` for multiple choices and then get selected index...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare strings like this

```
 if(intent.getStringExtra("answer").equals(getResources().getString(R.string.answerstring)))
    {
    Toast.makeText("Answer is correct").show();
    }
```

But it is better to do these with integers.

Comment: Thank for this. it works a treat.  I will now try to do it with integers as it is less messy.

Answer (score 0):

In Check question class put the following

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
        answer = extras.getString("answer");

    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, but an error comes for 'answer' and when I create a local variable for it, it says that it cannot be resolved to a local variable.

Comment: That might be because you didnt declare the variable **String answer**

Answer (score 0):

Why `getStringExtra()`? I see you put an `int` there: `myIntent.putExtra("answer", 3);`, hence `getStringExtra()` will return null, I believe. 
Try using instead: `getIntExtra()`, then you compare the integers.

Probably a bit off topic, but here's a small suggestion. All those 4 methods contains duplicate code, the only thing that is different is the answer. You could create a single method that takes as parameter the answer, and use it everywhere.

Something like this:

```
public void answerPressed(View view, int answer){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(AskQuestion.this, CheckQuestion.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("answer", answer); //Optional parameters
        AskQuestion.this.startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Now you can use only this single method for any answer:

```
answerPressed(view, 1);
answerPressed(view, 2); 
//.. and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

You put an Integer on your intent, but you want to get a string (getStringExtra) in your new Activity. Try to put a string (eg wrap in in ""), or get the value as an integer.